# Rails Creating a Valid JSON object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I could use your helping creating a valid JSON object in Rails.

Here is an example of a valid JSON object that I'm using in the jQuery plugin: https://drew.tenderapp.com/kb/autosuggest-jquery-plugin

```
var data = {items: [
    {value: "21", name: "Mick Jagger"},
    {value: "43", name: "Johnny Storm"},
    {value: "46", name: "Richard Hatch"},
    {value: "54", name: "Kelly Slater"},
    {value: "55", name: "Rudy Hamilton"},
    {value: "79", name: "Michael Jordan"}]};
```

Within Rails I'm creating my object as follows:

```
@projects = Projects.all
@projectlist = Array.new
@projectlist << {
  :items => @projects.map { |project|
    {
      :name => space.name,
      :value => space.id
    }
  }
}
```

But this ends up outputting like so which ERRORs by the plugin:

```
[{"items":[{"value":74,"name":"XXXXXX"},{"value":71,"name":"XXXXXX"},{"value":70,"name":"XXXXXX"}]}]
```

Looks like there is a [] around the initial {} any idea why that's happening and how to build a valid JSON object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply assign `@projectlist` to a `Hash`, like so:

**EDIT** After looking at the plugin's API, I've come to the conclusion that you need to convert your `value`s to strings first:

```
@projects = Projects.all
@projectlist = {
  :items => @projects.map { |project|
    {
      :name => space.name,
      :value => space.id.to_s
    }
  }
}
```

Since you're initializing `@projectlist` to an `Array` and pushing the `Hash` onto it, you're getting those wrapping `[]` characters.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, but I'm still confused, the jquery plugin seems to error if there is a " around the "name" or "value" is that a bug in my rails code or the jQuery plugin?

Comment: @AnApprentice That is what valid JSON is supposed to look like, so it seems that it could be a bug in the jQuery plugin.

Comment: and there's no quotes around the actual value's value

Comment: @AnApprentice If the datatype of a value is not a string, then there shouldn't be quotes around the value.

Comment: bu there should be quotes around name and value? why are they being outputted there by rails?

Comment: @AnApprentice Um, what? I don't understand, your output is valid JSON.

Comment: crap so the plugin is junk: http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin

Comment: @AnApprentice Your JSON output is fine, if you're still having problems then it's a bug with the jQuery plugin, that's all.

Comment: @AnApprentice Show me your JSON after my change.

Comment: JSON after the change: {"items":[{"value":74,"name":"Empty Goodness"},{"value":71,"name":"QA - 4 XXXX"},{"value":70,"name":"QA - XXXXX XXXXXX"}]}

Comment: Then in Rails in the view I have:       <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
       var data = <%=@projectlist.to_json%>};

       $("#textarea-test").autoSuggest(data.items, {}       });

      });
      </script>

Comment: Which then errors with: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &"

Comment: I think that helped but it didn't solve it. Instead of doing var data = <%=@projectlist.to_json%>};, I manually pasted the JSON object being made: var data = {"items":[{"value":74,"name":"Empty Goodness"},{"value":71,"name":"QA - 4 XXXXX"},{"value":70,"name":"QA - XXXXX"},]};   And that ended up working!!! so something in the way rails is rendering is the issue

Comment: What's that trailing `};` you have here? `var data = <%=@projectlist.to_json%>};` Get rid of the trailing `}` there, but leave the `;`.

Comment: @jacob, just noticed that! and removed it still erroring though.. I should add this is in a jquery-ui modal that is being creating through a .js call like so: $('#dialog-new-content').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial =>"messages/new"'); I think something in this process is breaking it

Comment: @AnApprentice Please format your code using the \` characters.

Comment: @AnApprentice On this line: `$("#textarea-test").autoSuggest(data.items, {} });` get rid of the last `}` character, it should look like this: `$("#textarea-test").autoSuggest(data.items, {});`

Comment: @Jacob, that's done, I just removed all the settings to keep it cleaner for you.. I think it's something to do with the rails, escape_partial

Comment: This is what rails is sending to the plugin: "{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"74\",\"name\":\"Empty Goodness\"},{\"value\":\"71\",\"name\":\"QA - 4 Teammembers\"},{\"value\":\"70\",\"name\":\"QA - Controller\"},{\"value\":\"72\",\"name\":\"QA - Reply\"},{\"value\":\"75\",\"name\":\"QA - Not My Project\"},{\"value\":\"14\",\"name\":\"QA - One Teammember\"},{\"value\":\"80\",\"name\":\"Sun Time\"}]}"

Comment: @AnApprentice To be honest, I think I sufficiently answered your original question - there really shouldn't be an ongoing dialog which modify your original requirements. We're not here to hold your hand, we're here to answer specific questions.

Comment: @AnApprentice What part of "edit your question with formatted code" doesn't click?

Comment: The issue was Rails formatting the JSON in the .js response. Using .html_safe in the .js response fixed the issue.

Comment: @AnApprentice: Way to give thanks through a downvote for all the time he took to entertain you. Sure, you could have undone your upvote and left it at that, but to further downvote just because you realized it was a completely different issue from what the answer was addressing is just stupid.